# How to get Node js API get response for Angular js API request

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have created an API that contains all the information stored in the database. I want to pass "from date" and "to date" as two variables in Node.js API to fetch requested date from AngularJS.

What is the way to achieve that, how should the get method be so that it will respond back all the available data between the given date range?

Comment: You can pass this parameters in query ('http://api.com?fromdate=01012001&toDate=01012002') but if you have to pass more infos you should consider doing a POST method

Comment: yes exactly did this and got output, thank you.

Comment: Glad this help!